# Is there a word for being able to type without looking?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a word for the ability to type without looking?

ex:
Because bob is _______ he can watch the lecturer and type simultaneously.

Comment: The word you are looking for is Awesome...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are two possible candidates for your blank:

> Because Bob is **touch-typing,** he can watch the lecturer and type simultaneously.

and

> Because Bob is **a touch-typist,** he can watch the lecturer and type simultaneously.

Comment: subtle potential point of confusion: i believe "touch typing" is often conflated with _how_ one types.  "touch type" is the opposite of "hunt and peck", even though one could and hunt and peck without looking (i do so at 100wpm), or need to look while using the home row.

Comment: @Eevee I don't think so. Erik is absolutely correct.

Comment: Touché!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

I would fill your blank with "a touch typist."
However, if your writing is meant to be more colloquial, you might say "Because Bob types by touch."

Comment: Perhaps "touch-type" as a conjoined word would work rather than the phrase touch typist?

Comment: You could certainly say "Because Bob touch types..."

Comment: I meant "Because Bob can touch-type he can watch the lecturer and type simultaneously."

Comment: That certainly works, although I'd replace the hyphen with a space (Because Bob can touch type, ...). The preference for a hyphen over a space can vary regionally, though.

Comment: @timothy.s.lau - I think your sentence is fine, with the hyphen.

Comment: I have only ever heard the phrase "types by touch" in the context of *explaining* what "touch typing" means.  I wouldn't ever say "Bob types by touch" in any writing of any formality level, just as you would never, ever hear anyone say "he doesn't have the music memorized, he just reads by sight".  It would **always** be "he just sight reads".

Answer (score 2):

The German expression is "blind schreiben" ( to type blind/blindly) meaning someone can type without looking at the keys. I just have to look whether this expression is also used in English or whether there is another expression.

Added: No, the English expression is to touch-type. I like the German metaphor. Actually I find the English expression a bit curious as you can't type without touching the keys.

Comment: It's because you type by touch (or by feel, using your sense of touch as your only sensory input) instead of type by sight (or by vision, using your eyesight as your sensory input) ... the phrases by sight, by touch, by smell, etc, refer to sensory input.

Comment: It's because you touch-type, not sight-type or taste-type. A touch typist relies on touch alone, not on sight or smell or mice.

Answer (score 0):

I have heard people saying "blind-typing".
For example, this website - [TypingStudy](http://www.typingstudy.com) uses the expression as well.

Comment: Welcome to [ELU.SE] @Annil. The page you link mentions touch typing 6 times and blind-typing not at all. It makes for a stronger answer when you support it with external material, but it is better if the linked material says what you say it does 
:-)